# How can we prove that a stochastic process converges to a deterministic value?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, gradient-flows

As an illustrative example, consider a modified O-U process $dX_t = -X_tdt + \exp(-t)dW_t$. It is not too hard to understand that after a while the behaviour is dominated by the deterministic component, which will drive the process to $0$ almost surely (for instance by showing that its asymptotic mean and variance converge to 0).

**My question is the following**: are there any results on proving such a convergence from the generator directly? Formally, I have a (as well-behaved as you wish) generator $\mathcal{A}_t f(x) = \lim_{s \to 0+}\frac{\mathbb{E}[f(X_{t+s}) \mid X_t=x] - f(x)}{s}$, and a known value $x^*$, for which I want to verify that $X_t \to x^*$ a.s.. Can this be done directly by checking some properties of $\mathcal{A}_t$.

My first idea was to simply find conditions under which $\mathcal{A}_t$ converges to a $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$ for which the Dirac $\delta_{x^*}$ is invariant. This is of course insufficient: it may happen that the decay in the process is too fast to eventually reach the desired asymptotic (imagine adding a $\exp(-t)$ in the drift of the OU above).

For context, I am trying to understand the convergence of continuous-time approximations of stochastic gradient descent (see, e.g., https://jmlr.org/papers/v20/17-526.html) in terms of their generator.

Thanks!

Comment: In your first paragraph you claim that in order to show convergence to zero almost surely it is enough to show the asymptotic mean and variance tend to zero, how do you go about showing this?

Comment: The distribution at time t is Gaussian, so it's fully characterised by its mean and covariance

Comment: This characterizes the distribution yes  but why does this necessarily imply the paths of the process will tend to zero almost surely, in general this need not be the case ?

Comment: It would be of great interest if there was a way to characterize convergence to zero almost surely by looking only at the asymptotic moments but I wouldn’t be sure if this can be done in general (by in general I mean even if you have an OU process similar to the above but with a general time dependent function in the diffusion rather than a decaying exponential) , this was why I was wondering if you had any insight after your comment in the first paragraph.

Comment: In this particular case the standard strong law of large numbers for Brownian motion gives convergence to zero almost surely as the solution is just a Brownian motion times a decaying exponential, but if one could obtain convergence to zero almost surely by ONLY using the asymptotic moments that would be very interesting indeed! Is this just a general fact about continuous Gaussian processes perhaps ?

Comment: I think it should be a general rule yes. Using Chebyshev's inequality you get $P(|X(t) - \mu(t)| > \epsilon) < \sigma(t)^2/\epsilon^2$, then you take an increasing sequence of $t_n$ such that $\sigma(t_n)^2 < 1/n^2$ (it must exist as the variance goes to 0) and then apply Borel-Cantelli as usual to prove a.s. convergence.

Comment: This only proves that 0 is an adherence point almost surely, but the process cannot have another adherence point as you can repeat the argument for a subsequence.

Comment: On the other hand, the sequence is eventually bounded with probability 1 (in the sense, the probability of the limsup of the centered process being less than any positive number is 1 and same for the liminf) so it has to converge almost surely to the asymptotic mean.

Answer (score 1):

Set initial condition $X_{0}=x_{0}=x^{*}=0$ for simplicity. We can identify its long-term behaviour by studying its density $p(t,x)$ and thus the corresponding Fokker-Plank equation (in terms of the adjoint of the generator $A^{*}$)

$$\partial_{t}p(t,x)=A^{*}p(t,x)=\partial_{x}(-xp(t,x))-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}(e^{-2t}p(t,x))$$
with initial data $p(x,0)=\delta_{x}$.

I plan to return to try to solve this or at least use parabolic estimates to get limiting behaviour, but I am not sure how doable it is especially because of the $e^{-2t}$ factor ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292544/understanding-the-fokker-planck-equation-for-non-stationary-processes) they discuss the similar issue of time-dependent coefficients). Did you also want an exact solution?

If you also want an SDE perspective on more general drifts see ["An SDE perspective on stochastic convex optimization"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.02750.pdf) where they study invariant measure limits.

Comment: Thanks I'll check the ref!